# What is this green semi-aquatic (semi-tropical) plant?

Tags: identification

I have seen a lot of these plants in offices and homes in China. In the picture I can see lucky bamboo (Dracaena braunii) but what's the other plant?  There's no heating so I assume that the room temperature is able to support both the plant and the warm water fish ( guppy ).

[image: vase with plants and fish]

and a close up of the roots and fish

[image: close up of the roots]

Comment: Sure looks like bamboo with water roots.  What is that package of 'stuff' in the first picture?

Comment: Looks like fish food from the pictures on the packet.

Comment: @stormy it is bamboo :)

Comment: OK I read more closely, sigh.  The other plant looks like Pothos.  What is the problem?  Hah, now I see the package more closely.

Comment: @stormy what I meant is, I think the other plant is a young proper bamboo vs the lucky "bamboo".

Comment: Ahhhh.  Just bamboo.  Welp, bamboo is pretty much semi aquatic.  But pothos should be in soil.  I've never had a lucky bamboo!  Maybe I should get one?!

Comment: There is the curly cue stuff that looks like lucky bamboo treatment.  Haven't seen proper bamboo done this way but completely doable.  What is the story here, Graham?  ID of this bamboo is out of my league!  Grasses are an amazing plant to learn to ID...what I think I am seeing are actual flowers of this bamboo?  I think I know why Bamboo chose this name for her pen name.  Stronger than concrete, brick and tensile strength greater than steel?  Whoa!

Comment: Boy sometimes I can be so slow...you are saying there are 2 types of bamboo including the pothos in that vase?  That would make sense.  Those flowers need to be looked at closely as they are the best way to ID a bamboo or any grass.  Are the flowers part of the 'proper bamboo' not the lucky?

Comment: I don't know about pothos but the curly one is lucky bamboo, and the other one according to spouse is ordinary bamboo. Just don't know which one.

Comment: The curly one would be domesticated lucky bamboo the other a blooming OTHER bamboo and those 3 leaves in  the first pic look like pothos.  Let's look at those 'flowers'...

Comment: I am so confused by these answers. Primarily because of our readily available matriarch, @Bamboo. So when you say "bamboo" do you mean "bamboo" or do you mean @Bamboo? Or are you you referring to the plant's improper ID of bamboo although it's not even related to bamboo? I'm bamboozled...It's a "who's on first" scenario here.

Comment: @Brenn I am referring to Bambusoideae but I think Stormy is saying it's not a Bambusoideae but pothos.

Comment: Gotcha! ;) You're referring to bamboo! I was kinda joking the whole time, but... it's still confusing.

Answer (score 2):

I should read the question more clearly:

Yes there is lucky bamboo (see below) and pothos, *Epipremnum aureum*. The other species that is just too out of focus to get a fix on the ID, but could be an actual bamboo. Whilst there are some aquatic and marginal bamboos, that is certainly not true of all of them and given the presence of pothos which is most certainly not aquatic I would suggest that the bamboo is likely to be a readily available form for flower arranging which is what this is (plus fish). Long term I can't see this working.

---

Original Answer:

It is *Dracaena braunii* (syn. *Dracaena sanderiana*), commonly called "Lucky Bamboo". It is not a bamboo or even remotely related (it is more closely related to *Sansevieria* or Mother-in-law's Tongue). It is not aquatic or even semi-aquatic and will ultimately die if submerged, although it will put up with this abuse for a long period of time. If fertilised, the water not too deep and a significant proportion of the plant out of the water it is possible to keep them growing in water without soil. The guppies are probably providing the nutrients to keep it going - please don't add fertiliser with the fish still there as it will kill the fish.

Comment: Why do you think this won't work long term? Pothos is grown in water and so is Dracaena braunii

Comment: Pothos is often grown above aquariums and allowed to drape down meaning that it does not get submerged deeply. Parts that go deeper and any leaves below the surface will rot away. Plants need oxygen and non-aquatic plants are not able to get oxygen to parts well below the surface. Dracaena is similar - parts starved of oxygen will rot. Note I said I couldn't see this working long term - this could take six months to a year maybe even longer, but the plants will not live their full natural lifespan.